# Converting sets of integers into ranges using C#

Tags: c#, algorithm

What's the most idiomatic way to convert a set of integers into a set of ranges?

E.g. given the set {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 11} I want to get { {0,4}, {7,9}, {11,11} } using C#

This question is already answered in C++ @ [Solution in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305767/converting-sets-of-integers-into-ranges)

Comment: Do the ranges need to be contiguous?

Answer (score 11):

This isn't very efficient, but it *is* idiomatic:

```
var nums = new HashSet<int>{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 11};
IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> ranges = Enumerable.Zip(
    nums.Where(n => !nums.Contains(n - 1)),
    nums.Where(n => !nums.Contains(n + 1)),
    Tuple.Create);
```

More efficient, assuming it's sorted:

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> GetContiguousRanges(IEnumerable<int> nums)
{
    int start = nums.First();
    int last = start - 1;
    foreach (int i in nums)
    {
        if (i != last + 1)
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(start, last);
            start = i;
        }
        last = i;
    }
    yield return Tuple.Create(start, last);
}
```

Comment: `(x, y) => Tuple.Create(x, y)` can be shorted to just `Tuple.Create`.

Answer (score 3):

This should be a pretty straightforward transliteration from the post you mentioned.  Make sure you put this code in a class somewhere, C# code has to be in a class.  I'm assuming you are not very familiar with C#, so I'll do enough to show the similarities and differences, and hopefully you can handle the rest.

```
struct Range
{
    public Range (int start, int end) { this.start = start; this.end = end; }
    public int start;
    public int end;
}

public static void SetToRanges(Dictionary<int,bool> indices, List<Range> ranges) 
{
    Range r = new Range(int.MinValue, int.MaxValue);
    foreach (int i in indices.Keys)
    {
        // translate rest of code here
    }
    ranges.Add(r);
    return ranges;
}
```

For a more idiomatic soluiton, I would return an `IEnumerable<Range>`, so the "list" can be built and iterated simultaneously:

```
public static IEnumerable<Range> SetToRanges(Dictionary<int, bool> indices)
{
     // instead of "ranges.Add(r)", use "yield return r".
     // This returns multiple values in order from the function, that can
     // be iterated with "foreach (Range i in SetToRanges(foo))"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try K-means clustering to get the ranges.  You'll need to specify how many different ranges you want.

Comment: -1 : K-means for that ? Won't even works. Ranges are here consecutives numbers.

Comment: @Loic -- The post doesn't say the ranges must include consecutive numbers.  I even asked the question.