# converting a list of integers into range in python

Tags: python, list, range, integer

Is there something existing in python that can convert an increasing list of integers into a range list

E.g. given the set {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 11} I want to get { {0,4}, {7,9}, {11,11} }.

I can write a program to do this, but want to know if there is an inbuilt function in python

Comment: Well, I can say with confidence that I don't know of such a function. It is a lot harder to say with confidence that something I'm not aware of doesn't exist....

Comment: Almost the same question was asked and answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429510/pythonic-way-to-convert-a-list-of-integers-into-a-string-of-comma-separated-range/3430231#3430231

Comment: I think your proposed result should really be a list of ranges.. cf. my answer below!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Using [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) produces a concise but tricky implementation:

```
import itertools

def ranges(i):
    for a, b in itertools.groupby(enumerate(i), lambda pair: pair[1] - pair[0]):
        b = list(b)
        yield b[0][1], b[-1][1]

print(list(ranges([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 11])))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 4), (7, 9), (11, 11)]
```

Comment: This is really useful, I'm wondering if you could explain how this method works so I can understand the functionality.  this would be great if possible.

Comment: To handle non-unique and non-sorted input surround 'i' with 'sorted(set(i))', see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43091576/1201614

Comment: This recipe is also available in `more_itertools.consecutive_groups`.  See demonstration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47642650/4531270).

Comment: 1 letter variable names is the worst crime!

Comment: @openCivilisation - the key insight is the lambda over the enumeration pairs.
You are making a list of (idx, elem). For example, with `data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 11]` the result of `list(map(lambda p: p[1] - p[0], enumerate(data)))` is `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3]`. Essentially, for each consecutive run of data, the difference of an element with its index forms this pattern. The pattern is sorted if the data is sorted. If you group by this number, you get your elements in groupings suitable for conversion to a range.

Answer (score 16):

You can use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) and a combination of [enumerate()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [itertools.groupby()](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 11]
>>> [[t[0][1], t[-1][1]] for t in
... (tuple(g[1]) for g in itertools.groupby(enumerate(l), lambda (i, x): i - x))]
[[0, 4], [7, 9], [11, 11]]
```

---

First, `enumerate()` will build tuples from the list items and their respective index:

```
>>> [t for t in enumerate(l)]
[(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 7), (6, 8), (7, 9), (8, 11)]
```

Then `groupby()` will group those tuples using the difference between their index and their value (which will be equal for consecutive values):

```
>>> [tuple(g[1]) for g in itertools.groupby(enumerate(l), lambda (i, x): i - x)]
[((0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)), ((5, 7), (6, 8), (7, 9)), ((8, 11),)]
```

From there, we only need to build lists from the values of the first and last tuples of each group (which will be the same if the group only contains one item).

You can also use `[(t[0][1], t[-1][1]) ...]` to build a list of range tuples instead of nested lists, or even `((t[0][1], t[-1][1]) ...)` to turn the whole expression into a iterable `generator` that will lazily build the range tuples on the fly.

Comment: In which Python versions does the lambda argument unpacking work? `python3.9 -c 'fn1 = lamba (a, b): a + b'` `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` --- I think it was only in the obsolete Python 2. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892989/what-is-the-good-python3-equivalent-for-auto-tuple-unpacking-in-lambda --- OK, I have found the PEP for this: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/ --- IMHO the answer should be fixed.

Answer (score 15):

This is an improvement over the very elegant [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4629241/1201614). This one covers **non-unique** and **non-sorted** input and is **python3** compatible too:

```
import itertools

def to_ranges(iterable):
    iterable = sorted(set(iterable))
    for key, group in itertools.groupby(enumerate(iterable),
                                        lambda t: t[1] - t[0]):
        group = list(group)
        yield group[0][1], group[-1][1]
```

Example:

```
>>> x
[44, 45, 2, 56, 23, 11, 3, 4, 7, 9, 1, 2, 2, 11, 12, 13, 45]

>>> print( list(to_ranges(x))) 
[(1, 4), (7, 7), (9, 9), (11, 13), (23, 23), (44, 45), (56, 56)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Generating range pairs:

```
def ranges(lst):
    s = e = None
    r = []
    for i in sorted(lst):
        if s is None:
            s = e = i
        elif i == e or i == e + 1:
            e = i
        else:
            r.append((s, e))
            s = e = i
    if s is not None:
        r.append((s, e))
    return r
```

Example:

```
>>> lst = [1, 5, 6, 7, 12, 15, 16, 17, 18, 30]
>>> print repr(ranges(lst))
[(1, 1), (5, 7), (12, 12), (15, 18), (30, 30)]
```

As a generator:

```
def gen_ranges(lst):
    s = e = None
    for i in sorted(lst):
        if s is None:
            s = e = i
        elif i == e or i == e + 1:
            e = i
        else:
            yield (s, e)
            s = e = i
    if s is not None:
        yield (s, e)
```

Example:

```
>>> lst = [1, 5, 6, 7, 12, 15, 16, 17, 18, 30]
>>> print repr(','.join(['%d' % s if s == e else '%d-%d' % (s, e) for (s, e) in gen_ranges(lst)]))
'1,5-7,12,15-18,30'
```

Answer (score 3):

This generator:

```
def ranges(p):
    q = sorted(p)
    i = 0
    for j in xrange(1,len(q)):
        if q[j] > 1+q[j-1]:
            yield (q[i],q[j-1])
            i = j
    yield (q[i], q[-1])

sample = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 11]
print list(ranges(sample))
print list(ranges(reversed(sample)))
print list(ranges([1]))
print list(ranges([2,3,4]))
print list(ranges([0,2,3,4]))
print list(ranges(5*[1]))
```

Produces these results:

```
[(0, 4), (7, 9), (11, 11)]
[(0, 4), (7, 9), (11, 11)]
[(1, 1)]
[(2, 4)]
[(0, 0), (2, 4)]
[(1, 1)]
```

Note that runs of repeated numbers get *compressed*. I don't know if that's what you want. If not, change the `>` to a `!=`.

I understand your question. I looked into `itertools` and tried to think of a solution that could be done in a couple of lines of Python, which would have qualified as *"almost a built in"*, but I couldn't come up with anything.

Answer (score 3):

As there hasn't been a new answer for 2 years or so, here's one for zombie lovers!

If you don't want to use itertools or a generator, the following uses logic(!). It uses a set (cf. the question!) for input and returns a list of proper ranges as a result; it's easy enough to adjust the code to suit though.

```
def ranges(l_set: set) ->list:
    rb_set = sorted(l_set - {i +1 for i in l_set})
    re_set = sorted(l_set - {i -1 for i in l_set})
    return [range(rb_set[i], re_set[i]+1) for i in range(len(rb_set))]
```

For example:

```
>>>ranges({6, 9, 10, 7, 8, 2, 3, 14})
[range(2, 4), range(6, 11), range(14, 15)]

>>>ranges({6, 7, 3, 15, 8, 5, 12, 0, 12, 7, 15, 6, 14, 8, 16})
[range(0, 1), range(3, 4), range(5, 9), range(12, 13), range(14, 17)]
```

Comment: As an improvement I suggest to use `rb_set = sorted(l_set.difference(i+1 for i in l_set))` as it avoids creating another temporary set in memory. Also for the final list you can use `[range(b, e+1) for b, e in zip(rb_set, re_set)]` or if you want to have tuples instead just `list(zip(rb_set, re_set))`.

Comment: Just curious: Is there a reason somebody mightn't want to use itertools or a generator?

Comment: @MichaelScheper, some people don't like to import moudles that they don't strictly need. As for generators, they need to be generated - and sometimes there is an advantage to just having the object.

Answer (score 2):

Related questions [for the case when step sizes other than 1 are of interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847601/convert-list-of-numbers-to-string-ranges) and a near duplicate of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154249/identify-groups-of-continuous-numbers-in-a-list). A solution for either case that performs well is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59255692/1089161).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing built-in, or in any libraries that I know of.  Not very helpful, I know, but I've never come across anything like what you want.

Here are some ideas for your program atleast (in C++, but it can give you some other ideas):

[Converting sets of integers into ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305767/converting-sets-of-integers-into-ranges)

Answer (score 1):

In the case there is no such feature in python, here is an implementation

```
p = []
last = -2                                                            
start = -1

for item in list:
    if item != last+1:                        
        if start != -1:
            p.append([start, last])
        start = item
    last = item

p.append([start, last])
```

Answer (score 1):

Put it shorter:

```
ranges=lambda l:map(lambda x:(x[0][1],x[-1][1]),map(lambda (x,y):list(y),itertools.groupby(enumerate(l),lambda (x,y):x-y)))
```

Comment: Shorter is no improvement, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I think the other answers are hard to understand, and probably inefficient. Hope this is easier and faster.

```
def ranges(ints):
    ints = sorted(set(ints))
    range_start = previous_number = ints[0]
    for number in ints[1:]:
        if number == previous_number + 1:
            previous_number = number
        else:
            yield range_start, previous_number
            range_start = previous_number = number
    yield range_start, previous_number
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension:

```
s = {0,1,2,3,4,7,8,9,11}
r = [(a,b) 
    for l in [sorted([i for i in s if {i-1,i+1} - s])]
    for a,b in zip(l[::2],l[1::2]+[l[-1]])]
print(r)
```

yields

```
[(0, 4), (7, 9), (11, 11)]
```