# How to condense sequence of half integers to string expressions with colon operators? (How to convert list to string)

Tags: arrays, matlab

Is there a built-in function in Matlab that condenses sequence of half integers to expressions with colon operators?

For example, `[1:4,5:.5:7]` gives

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7
```

Given a double array such as `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7]`, is there a convenient way to convert it back to `[1:4,5:.5:7]` — or equally valid, `[1:5,5.5:.5:7]` — as a string?

Comment: I'd be surprised if this is built in, but you could build such a function. It's not easy though, and the solution is ambiguous: `[1:4,5:.5:7]` and `[1:5,5.5:.5:7]` are the same!

Comment: @Argyll Would you be happy with any of those possible solutions? Or what's the criterion to choose one

Comment: To add to Cris Luengo's comments: some of the complications are (1) floating-point inaccuracies in detecting runs with the same step (try for example `format long, diff([7.1 7.2 7.3 7.4])`), and (2) avoiding to output `[1 3 5 7 9 10 11 12]` as `'[1:2:7 9 10:12]'` (I assume that both `'[1:2:7 9:12]'` and `'[1:2:9 10:12]'` would be valid)

Comment: @LuisMendo: I would be happy with either solution. The desired output is just that it is condensed. The numbers themselves are always half integers. So without generalizing the problem, floating-point inaccuracy wouldn't hurt in my application.

Comment: A similar question in Python (but doesn't take into account floating-point accuracy issues): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43788106/

Comment: @Aziz: Thanks for the link. In other words, scan from left to right and group until step changes. Would you recommend that in Matlab too?

Comment: I didn't notice the "half integer" spec. That solves the floating point accuracy issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution that

- Adequately handles **numbers that don't form a range**. For example, `[1 3 5 9]` will be output as `'[1:2:5 9]'`. Similarly, `[1 3 5 9 11]` would give `'[1:2:5 9 11]'`.
- Omits specifying **step `1`**. For example, `[9 3 4 5]` would give `[9 3:5]`.
- Omits **unnecessary brackets**. For example, `[8 6 4 2]` would give `'8:-2:2'`,  and `5` would give `'5'`.
- Allows **empty input**. So `[]` would give `'[]'`.

```
x = [2 4.5 7 9.5 9 8 7 6 5 15 7.5 7 6.5 6 9 11]; % example input
sep = ' '; % define separator; it could also be comma
str = ''; % initiallize output
k = 1; % first number not processed yet
while k<=numel(x)
    m = find(diff([diff(x(k:end)) inf]), 1) + 1; % may be empty
    if m>2 % if non-empty and at least 2: range found (at least 3 numbers)
        ini = x(k);
        ste = x(k+1)-x(k);
        fin = x(k+m-1);
        if ste~=1
            str = [str num2str(ini) ':' num2str(ste) ':' num2str(fin)];
        else
            str = [str num2str(ini) ':' num2str(fin)];
        end
        k = k+m; % m numbers have been processed
    else % no range: include just one number
        str = [str num2str(x(k))];
        k = k+1; % 1 number has been processed
    end
    str = [str sep]; % add separator
end
str = strip(str,sep); % this removes trailing space/comma, if it exists. For pre-2016b, use `strtrim`
if any(str==sep) || isempty(str)
    str = ['[' str ']']; % brackets are required
end
```

Examples / tests:

- `[2 4.5 7 9.5 9 8 7 6 5 15 7.5 7 6.5 6 9 11]` gives `'[2:2.5:9.5 9:-1:5 15 7.5:-0.5:6 9 11]'`
- `[1.5 16 -0.5 -7 -9 -11]` gives `'[1.5 16 -0.5 -7:-2:-11]'`
- `[4 2 0 -2 5 12 19]` gives `'[4:-2:-2 5:7:19]'`
- `[-2 0 2.5 5.5]` gives `'[-2 0 2.5 5.5]'`
- `[2 3 4 10 7 8]` gives `'[2:4 10 7 8]'`
- `[6 4.5 3]` gives `'6:-1.5:3'`
- `[3 4 5 6]` gives `'3:6'`
- `42` gives `'42'`
- `[]` gives `'[]'`

The code consists of a loop that searches for the maximum-length range starting at the current position, and then mover forward. The **trickiest part** is the line

> `m = find(diff([diff(x(k:end)) inf]), 1) + 1; % may be empty`

This tries to find the maximum length `m` of numbers that form a range, starting from the current position `k`. `diff(x(k:end))` computes consecutive differences, and the outer `diff` detects changes in those difference. The first such change, computed with `find(..., 1)`, indicates the first number that doesn't belong to the range. There are five cases, the second of which explains why the `inf` is needed:

- *Proper range of 3 or more numbers, followed by at least a number not in that range*. For example, if `x(k:end)` is `[3 5 7 15]` we have `diff(x(k:end))` equal to `[2 2 8]`, `diff([diff(x(k:end)) inf])` equal to `[0 6 inf]`, `find(..., 1)` gives `2`, and `m` is `3`.
- *Proper range of 3 or more numbers, which ends the array*. For example, if `x(k:end)` is `[3 5 7]` we have `diff(x(k:end))` equal to `[2 2]`, `diff([diff(x(k:end)) inf])` equal to `[0 inf]`, `find(..., 1)` gives `2`, and `m` is `3`. This is why `inf` is needed; without it the result would be `m=[]`, which would be incorrectly interpreted as "no range" by the `if` branch.
- *No proper range; there are more than 2 numbers remaining*. For example, if `x(k:end)` is `[3 6 7]` we have `diff(x(k:end))` equal to `[3 1]`, `diff([diff(x(k:end)) inf])` equal to `[-2 inf]`, `find(..., 1)` gives `1`, and `m` is `2`. This means that there *is* a range of two numbers; but it is not a *proper* range, so the `if` branch will disregard it, and execution will proceed with the `else` part.
- *No proper range; there are only 2 numbers remaining*. For example, if `x(k:end)` is `[3 6]` we have `diff(x(k:end))` equal to `3`, `diff([diff(x(k:end)) inf])` equal to `[inf]`, `find(..., 1)` gives `1`, and `m` is `2`. Again, there is a range of two numbers, but it is not a proper range. Note that without the included `inf` we would have `m=[]` instead of the "correct" `2`, but that would also be valid to trigger the `else` part (in which the actual value of `m` is not used).
- *No proper range; there is only 1 number remaining, that is, the current number ends the array*. For example, `if x(k:end)` is just `3` we have `diff(x(k:end))` equal to `[]`, `diff([diff(x(k:end)) inf])` equal to `[]`, `find(..., 1)` gives `[]`, and `m` is `[]`. Although `m` "should" be `1`, `[]` is just as valid to trigger the `else` part.

Note that, since the input contains integers or half integers, there are **no floating-point accuracy issues**, as those numbers are represented exactly up to ±`2^52`.

Comment: Nice. And thank you. Aside, what does the `inf]` part in `find(diff([diff(x(k:end)) inf]), 1)` do?

Comment: @Argyll I added an explanation (and slightly modified the code for clarity; now `m` is `find(..., 1) + 1`, so it can be interpreted as range length)

Comment: Thank you for the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

here's a simple loopy answer, given `x` is your vector, I chose `1e-10` to be the threshold of difference for floating point accuracy...

```
x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7];
dx=diff(x);
a=num2str(x(1)); % first step, start the range
for n=2:numel(dx)
    if abs(dx(n)-dx(n-1))>1e-10
        if dx(n-1)~=1
        a=[a ':' num2str(dx(n-1)) ':' num2str(x(n)), ' ', num2str(x(n+1)) ];
        else
       a=[a ':' num2str(x(n)), ' ', num2str(x(n+1)) ];
        end     
    end
end
a=[a ':' num2str(dx(end)) ':' num2str(x(end))]; % last step, close the range


> a =

    '1:5 5.5:0.5:7'
```

Comment: This produces `'2:3 4:6:4 10:-3:10 7:1:8'` for input `[2 3 4 10 7 8]`. Not incorrect, but probably not what the OP wants either

Comment: lol...  yes it doesnt include beautification yet for all case :)

Comment: Ya. Looking in comparison, I do appreciate the use of second `diff`. :)