# convert list of sequential number into interval or range

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 15, 16, 17]
```

I would like to get the result as:

```
b = [1-5, 8-11, 15-17]
```

since in my list `a` I have sequential number from `1 to 5, 8 to 11` and then `15 to 17`.

How should I do this in Python?

Comment: `4-3-2-1` series

Comment: What have you tried so far. Give us your [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628333/converting-a-list-of-integers-into-range-in-python/4629241#4629241) but with a little change  by [@luca](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628333/converting-a-list-of-integers-into-range-in-python):

```
import itertools

def to_ranges(iterable):
    iterable = sorted(set(iterable))
    for key, group in itertools.groupby(enumerate(iterable),
                                        lambda t: t[1] - t[0]):
        group = list(group)
        yield group[0][1], group[-1][1]


x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 15, 16, 17]
print( list(to_ranges(x)))
```

OUTPUT:

```
[(1, 5), (8, 11), (15, 17)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def range_extract(lst):
            'Yield 2-tuple ranges or 1-tuple single elements from list of increasing ints'
            lenlst = len(lst)
            i = 0
            while i< lenlst:
                low = lst[i]
                while i <lenlst-1 and lst[i]+1 == lst[i+1]: i +=1
                hi = lst[i]
                if   hi - low >= 2:
                    yield (low, hi)
                elif hi - low == 1:
                    yield (low,)
                    yield (hi,)
                else:
                    yield (low,)
                i += 1

    def printr(ranges):
            print( ','.join( (('%i-%i' % r) if len(r) == 2 else '%i' % r)
                             for r in ranges ) )

    if __name__ == '__main__':
            lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 15, 16, 17]
            x=range_extract(lst)
            print(list(x))

    # output : [(1, 5), (8, 11), (15, 17)]
```