# Python list to range

Tags: python, list, for-loop, range

I have the list

```
lst = [3, 5]
```

How to get a range for each item in the list like this ?

```
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

This is loop is obviously not working

```
for i in range(0, lst):
  print(i)
```

Comment: For each i you can construct your desired list as follows : L = [j for j in range(i)]. does this fit you ?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/q/4628333/19939086

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lst = [3, 5]
[list(range(x+1)) for x in lst]
#[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
```

Or simply:

```
for x in lst:
    print(list(range(x+1)))
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `range()` for each `end`; to include the `end` in the range, add 1:

```
>>> lst = [3, 5]
[3, 5]
>>> ranges = [range(end + 1) for end in lst]
[range(0, 4), range(0, 6)]
>>> for x in ranges:
...     print(list(x))
...
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```